# Is it possible to cross reference bash and python variables in python script

Tags: python, bash

I can get a value `n` when I run a shell command using `os.system` in the python script, but I also need to sum it up to get a total number for subsequent computation in the python script,

```
total=0
for i in xrange(1,8):
    os.system('n=$(qstat -n1 | grep -o node'+str(i)+' | wc -l)  && echo $n')
```

Is it possible? Also is it possible to use python variable in shell command, something like

```
os.system('echo $total')
```

Comment: I gave you what you wanted, but I don't think it's the best way to handle this. You could get os.system's output, or do all the work in python.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? This sounds like an XY Problem.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I just want to communicate with the input and output of shell command in Python script. Subprocess API works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `subprocess` module's `check_output` method like this

```
import subprocess
print sum(int(subprocess.check_output(["/bin/sh", "-c", "n=`expr {} + 1` && echo $n".format(i)])) for i in range(10))
```

**Output**

```
55
```

Comment: Thank you! It did just what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Use the shell's `export`command:

```
$ export ABC=1 # Set and export var in shell 
$ bash # Start another shell
$ echo $ABC # variable is still here
1
$ python # Start python still in the deeper shell
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from os import environ # import environnement
>>> environ['ABC'] # And here's the variable again (it's a string because the shell doesn't have types)
'1'
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! It clarifies something for me, however I want use bash variable in Python script. So subprocess is the appropriate choice.